# Variable in Runnable

Tags: android, variables, runnable

I create a Runnable in my class :

```
private Runnable monRun = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Log.i("PLAY", "" + play);
        if(play) {
           /* [...] */
        }
    }
};
```

Here, play is an instance variable of my class.

But, when I call my Runnable :

```
handler.postDelayed(monRun, 100);
```

the variable play is captured in Runnable and if I changed value in an other method of my class, play will not be changed in my Runnable

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you have **`play`** instance variable in your main `thread` and you are updating this variable in different `thread`.

Answer (score 0):

Variables in per-object implementations and lambda expressions always get copied, cause in the meanwhile those variables may even get out of scope and just die. Make them **copy a reference to an object** then.

I suggest you to enclose your variable play in an object, and pass that object to the `Runnable`:

```
class ObjectToPass {
    boolean play;

    public synchronized boolean getPlay() {
        return play;
    }

    public synchronized void setPlay(boolean play) {
       this.play = play;
    }
}


... // play is a ObjectToPass

private Runnable monRun = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Log.i("PLAY", "" + play.getVar());
        if(play.getVar()) {
           /* [...] */
        }
    }
};
```

The `synchronized` keyword is to avoid problems with thread safety on the play member. If the `Runnable` is called in the same thread you can (and you should) just avoid `synchronized`.

I also suggest you to pass a reference to the `ObjectToPass` via the constructor of a class conforming to Runnable, instead of using the per-object implementation. This will help you handle data better:

```
class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

    private ObjectToPass play;

    public MyRunnable(ObjectToPass play) {
        this.play = play;
    }

    @Override public void run() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: so what? just pass the MyRunnable object instead of the Runnable.